# Grouping items by attribute with AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm writing a small inventory app using Angular with Firebase as a backend for managing the inventory of a deep freezer (stuff could get lost in there forever!), and I'm having difficulty finding a good JSON structure. The data is a list of items in the freezer, each of which has a description, measurement, expiration date, and added (to the inventory) date.

I am using the excellent [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html) library which allows me to bind the item array directly to a scope while keeping the array in sync with Firebase. In my controller:

```js
var fireRef = new Firebase('https://frozenapp.firebaseio.com/items/');
var sync = $firebase(fireRef);
$scope.items = sync.$asArray();
```

In some places of the app, the items need to be listed individually. That way, I can filter them based on expiration date (e.g. items that have already expired or items that will expire soon).

However, in other places of the app, the items need to be grouped together by type. A type in this case would mean an item with the same description and measurement (e.g. Broccoli, 16oz). When the items are grouped by type, they will have a quantity property associated with them that I need to display as well. I will also need access to the set of associated expiration and added dates for each type. For example, there may be three Broccoli, 16oz items all of which have different expiration and added dates.

The problem is how to do this while keeping the data synced to the server. If my JSON structure is simply an array of items, I need to "collect" them into types for the second display style. If the structure is based on an item type with an array of added and associated expiration dates, then I need to "unpack" them into individual items for the first display style.

Here is a plunk of several different possible JSON structures I have come up with: http://plnkr.co/edit/PeqZH8Va86kz1c2fULPS

Comment: This question could easily warrant several chapters of a book. Could you pick a specific use case you would like to resolve? Something we can answer in a single page? As it stands, the question is, how do I structure data and write code for an entire app? Also, include some code for us to examine.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the different possibilities in your plunk are scenarios that would be useful for your app, then your answer to data organization is: use all of them.

Start by reading about [denormalizing data in Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html). If you're coming from a relational database background, it might feel a bit counter-intuitive to "duplicate" your data in Firebase. It might actually feel completely wrong having to maintain those "duplicate" data structures in your client code. But it's all right. :)

Also, the new [query methods](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-11-04-firebase-realtime-queries.html) might be helpful for your case.